# jQuery add close buttons dynamically on elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying adding fancy close buttons dynamically to html elements

code is:

```
function add_close_box(element,img_close_box,base_url_close_box){

   var i;
    $.each($('.'+element),function(i){

     $(this).addClass('close_box'+i);
     var x = $('.close_box'+i).offset().left;
     var y = $('.close_box'+i).offset().top;

    $('body').append('<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="img_close_box_'+i+'"><img src="'+base_url_close_box+img_close_box+'"></a>');
    $('.img_close_box_'+i).css({'position':'absolute','top':y-10,'left':x+$('.close_box'+i).width()-20});
    $('.img_close_box_'+i).live('click',function(){

    var hei = $('.'+element).height();
    $('.img_close_box_'+i+','+'.close_box'+i).hide();
   $.each('.'+element,function(e){ 
       $('.img_close_box_'+(e)).animate({
          'top':'-='+hei
       },0);
   });



  });
    });


}
```

it works good but when click on button and element is fadeOut() other close buttons doesn't follows their own related element cause of absolute position they remain in same positions while elements scroll up (first element fadeOut next element scroll up and close button remain in same position)

i would like that close buttons could follow their related element.

Also cause my lazy mind i would like to know if anyone knows some good jquery plugin to do what I'm trying to code, something with also ajax callback after closebox button click (do not reply to watch jQuery UI please :) )

thanks ;)

Comment: Does your "close" box has "position:relative" set?

Comment: did you mean element or button for close element?

Comment: anyway i just putted position:absolute to close button as you can see

Comment: did you know any other solution to append a close button to an element dinamically?

Comment: Have a placeholder DIV in your content and inject your button inside it.

Comment: yep that was standard way to do what i would like is to add them dinamically without pre-set a content div :(

Comment: yep i know :P thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have to make a few assumptions because you haven't posted your markup.  I think Diodeus is on the right track.  You're using absolute positioning for your new close button.  Absolute positioning will look up in the DOM until it finds a relatively positioned element to anchor the coordinates.  if the `element` you pass in doesn't have the property `position:relative` then the button could be positioned anywhere.

**Two possible fixes:**

Add relative positioning to everything you add the close button to:

```
element.css({'position':'relative'});
```

Obviously this will *replace* any other previously set positioning.  There's a chance this blows up your layout if you're adding close buttons all over the place.

The second option is to make sure the *only* relatively positioned element is something high in the DOM, so all of your close buttons are positioned based on the same thing.  It's a little hacky, but then you can position them based on the x and y of the element:

```
var x = element.position().x;  
var y = element.position().y;    
// you can add the necessary offsets like element width or height
```

Comment: After reading your question a little more carefully, I'm pretty sure you want the first option.  You'll have to make sure your layout can support it.